# Retrieve All Employees from Kronos WFC SOAP Service

Tags: soap

I am writing an application to comunicate with Kronos WFC to get all employee list (active and inactive) including all data, labor level and personal information.

I tried this query:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Kronos_WFC version="1.0">
    <Request Object="System" Action="Logon" Username="User" Password="Pwd" />
    <Request Object="System" Action="Load">
        <PersonInformation>
            <Identity>
                <PersonIdentity>
                    <PersonNumber>*</PersonNumber>
                </PersonIdentity>
            </Identity>
        </PersonInformation>
    </Request>
    <Request Object='System' Action='Logoff'/>
</Kronos_WFC>
```

but it seems to reject '*' wildcard. Always the response is failed, so, if i send any person number request retrieve whole person information only for that person number, not all employee list, anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you figured it out? I'm having the same issue! Thanks!

Comment: According to the people of kronos, this functionality will not be implemented, i solved my problem by getting all data from the view VP_ALLPERSONV42 located on the kronos database, hope it helps!

Comment: Is this one of those HyperQueries? Thanks! It helped a lot.

Comment: No, this is not a HyperQuery, this is a "default install time" view on database, you must have permissions on the view at least to query via SQL or via ORM if you are using it, i am developing an application to do that, is currently on client production environment, if you need me to help you, please feel free to **contact me**

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to query the view 'VP_ALLPERSONV42', this view comes by default on kronos install bundle, you must contact your DBA to get a "read only" access to the 'VP_ALLPERSONV42' view.

Keep in mind: Kronos labor levels are abstract, so you must analyze the view structure to determine which fields you are looking for and make the right level projection.

Hope it helps!